# Not able to Call the Handler

Tags: android, okhttp

I am trying to perform a Logout Operation on a button click from server but whenever i am clicking on Logout it stucks at SweetAlertDialogBox.

when i am debugging my code, debugger debugs the code well till line: " client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() { " inside the logoutservice() and after this instead of going down to " String message " , it actually terminates. it skips both on failure and onResponse methods

There is no Error mentioned in the Logcat

This is my button Click Code:-

```
 btnLogout = itemBuilder.setContentView(logoutIcon).build();
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.create();
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if (networkUtil.isConnected()) {
                        logoutService();
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this);
                        alertbox.setMessage("No network connection, Please try after some time");
                        alertbox.create();
                        alertbox.setCancelable(false);
                        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
    }
                        });
                        alertbox.show();
                    }
                }

            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

        }
    });
```

This is My Logout and Logoutservice Methods :-

```
    public void logout() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlertDialogActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmActivity.this,
            12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    stopService(new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, LocationTracker.class));
    System.exit(0);
}

  private void logoutService() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String requestURL = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.service_logout));
    JSONObject jsonrequest = new JSONObject();
    try {
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
        jsonrequest.accumulate("mobNo", pref.getValueFromSharePref("mobileno"));
        jsonrequest.accumulate("empAuthKey", pref.getValueFromSharePref("authKey"));
        jsonrequest.accumulate("logoutTime", simpleDateFormat.format(today));
        jsonrequest.accumulate("lat", "" + locationInfo.lastLat);
        jsonrequest.accumulate("lon", "" + locationInfo.lastLong);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonrequest.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(requestURL)
            .post(body).build();

    final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(AlarmActivity.this, cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
    pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
    pDialog.setTitleText("Loading, Please wait ...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        String status,message;
        Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    logout();
                } else if (msg.what == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (msg.what == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (msg.what == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this, "System Error Please try again...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseString = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    status = jsonResponse.getString("status");
                    message = jsonResponse.getString("message");

                    if (status.equals("success")) {
                        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        response.body().close();

                    } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
                        response.body().close();

                    } else if (status.equals("error")) {
                        if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        response.body().close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                    response.body().close();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me with this issue there is no error in the Logcat..

Comment: After you getting the success message close the dialog by pdialog.dismiss(); which ll close the dialog box.

Comment: @Mr.Popular its already there in the code  you can see.

Comment: please debug your code and check this **if (pDialog.isShowing())** what it  is return.. if it is return false your pDialog always show...

Comment: Your code may doesn't reach the pdialog.dismiss statement... Have u checkd whether ur code reaching dismiss() line by debugging??

Comment: @Mr.Popular: Sir when i am debugging my code, debugger debugs the code well till line: " client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() { "  and after this instead of goin down to " String message " , it actually terminates. it skips both on failure and onResponse methods

Comment: @NKmewara:   Sir can you please check again my code after debugging  i have changed my question a lil bit.

Comment: Those methods or callbacks like onpause() ondestroy() methods... They ll run whenever they needed to run I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use `Handler` inside `onResponse` to do something in UI thread , and so you should also dismiss SweetAlertDialog  in `handleMessage`

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
 //...
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i am already using a handler see        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

Comment: yes i see , i mean you should dismiss dialog in handleMessage , not inside onResponse direct

Comment: i have tried that as well but still issue is there ... after hours of debugging i can say code is not able to call the handler for sure... i don't know what i am missing as i have done similar sort of operations in a same manner

Comment: Sir when i am debugging my code, debugger debugs the code well till line     client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {     and after this instead of goin down String message , it actually terminates. it skips both on failure and onResponse methods

Comment: try String responseString = response.body().toString(); toString not string()

Comment: nothing happened...same thing happened again debugger terminates and  reached the last  " } " inside  onResponse()